# Create keyboard DLL

Tags: keyboard-layout, dll, keymap

I am struggling to find any resources on how to make a keyboard DLL.

I have previously looked at code samples, like http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Keyboard-Layout-Sample-b142d9e3 but even with what I deem as a decent understanding of quite a few programming languages, cannot make heads or tails of how to alter this sample to remap the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.

This tact came about because I failed to find a keyboard layout program that allowed adjusting the Windows key mapping.

Anyone got any good resources for learning how to write a keyboard DLL, in the hopes that this will allow altering the aforemention key?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the Windows key mapping? What have you previously tried? I've got a feeling there's an easier way to accomplish what you're trying to do than by building a whole new keyboard remapping DLL, when there are numerous solutions out there (AutoHotkey being the one which comes first to mind) which already implement one, and expose its interface in a way that's easier to implement against than the Windows C++ API.

Comment: A kiosk type application that needs to run on machines that may, or may not have admin rights, needs a way to disable/enable this key ad-hoc. As far as I am aware, ad-hoc adjusting keyboard mapping requires a restart of Windows, but swapping keyboard layouts doesn't require a restart, nor admin rights (Beyond the install of the keyboard at install of the kiosk application). Requiring / bundling a separate program to provide this functionality is not very desirable.

Comment: What are you trying to remap, just removing the ability to use the windows key, or are you wanting more?

Comment: I believe that being able to construct a keyboard DLL will allow more adjustments, but the main and currently desired ability is just to disable the Windows key.